# Indexing error when trying to assign a 3d matrix to a 2d matrix

Tags: matlab, indexing

I have a 3d matrix `A` of size `128 x 15 x 2`

I have another 2d column matrix `M` of size `128 x 1`

`M` has only 2 possible values, either `1` or `2` which should select the `128 x 15` data from depth index `1` or depth index `2` of `A`, one row vector at a time & stores it in matrix `B` which is also `128 x 15`.

I dont want to use a for loop going from 1 to 128 & depending on the corresponding `M` value, selecting 128 row vector from the 3d matrix depth 0 or 1.

I want to do this in a single assignment statement but am unable to as it gives me wrong indexing & mismatched dimensions.
I tried

```
B = A(:, :, M)
```

However, it generated a `128 x 15 x 128` 3d matrix which isn't what I was expecting. How can I index into the matrix the way that I would like to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is an easy way to accomplish what you want. First let us generate your data:

```
A = rand(128, 15, 2);
M = [ones(64,1); 2*ones(64,1)];
M = M(randperm(128),1);
```

Then you can index `A` using `M` just using logical indexing:

```
B = zeros(128,15);
B(M == 1,:) = A(M == 1,:,1);
B(M == 2,:) = A(M == 2,:,2);
```

Finally, you have the results in `B` which is `128*15`.

Comment: It gives me "Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch" error for the B assignment

Comment: This is the simple solution. The error you get is because the dimensions are wrong, it should be `A = rand(128, 15, 2);`.

Comment: @Adiel, you're right! I was writing the solution for smaller problem `8*5*2` and I forgot to change the dimensions when I posted the answer!

Answer (score 4):

This is because you select an *entire* 3D "slice" for each value in `M` since you've used that as the index for the third dimension.

So for example if `M = [1 2 1]`, you'll get 3 3D "slices" that consist of the first, second, and first slice, respectively.

Instead you probably want something like the following

```
% Shift the dimensions around a bit to bring the third dimension to the front
B = permute(A, [3 1 2]);

% Convert 1:numel(M) and M to linear indices
inds = sub2ind([size(B, 1), size(B, 2)], M, (1:numel(M)).');

% Reshape your matrix to be (128 * 2) x 15
C = reshape(B, [], size(B, 3));

% Index into this using the linear indexes computed above
output = C(inds, :);
```

Comment: I have yet not come across any of the functions you used. Is this the simplest approach? Can it be done without using the above built in functions

Comment: @KharoBangdo no it can't.  Also if you want to develop in MATLAB, all of the functions above are necessary to know if you want to write efficient code. You better start learning!

Comment: I tested the above 4 lines of code. The output matrix is 128 x 2 instead of 128 x 5. So, please modify the code

Comment: @KharoBangdo I apologize, it was a typo on my part. It has been updated.

Comment: This solution also works, +1, but the answer by @hmofrad takes 20% less time to execute for my code. Thanks